# Worksheet_Change & Range User Cell Protection

Tags: vba, excel

I have one worksheet that works with Worksheet_Change macros.

First one protect each cell that was modifed, but only direct interaction.

Sadly last two codes make changes in colums F:I, but it's not direct modification and the first code leaves those unprotected...

I need to protect those colums from user modification (but leave for VBA changes) and leave all other cells unprotected till they will be modified by an user. I tried already UserInterfaceOnly:=True but doesn't seems to work.

It's critical that all cells stay unprotected till change made by a user. Only Columns Range("F:I") should be user protected but not VBA.

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Athens"
        For Each cel In Target
            If cel.Value <> "" Then
                cel.Locked = True
                End If
        Next cel
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Athens"
```

Whole Code:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rC As Range
    Dim P2 As Range
    Dim cel As Range


        Application.EnableEvents = True
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Athens"
        For Each cel In Target
            If cel.Value <> "" Then
                cel.Locked = True
                End If
        Next cel
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Athens"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rC In Target.Cells
            Range("F" & rC.Row) = Now()
            Range("G" & rC.Row) = Environ("username")
        Next rC
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each P2 In Target.Cells
            Range("H" & P2.Row) = Now()
            Range("I" & P2.Row) = Environ("username")
        Next P2
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following to initiate the sheet protection. This will need to be run each time the workbook is opened

```
Public Sub InitiateSheetProtection()
    Dim strPassword As String
    strPassword = "Athens"

    With Sheets("YourSheetReferenceHere")
        .Unprotect Password:=strPassword
        .Cells.Locked = True
        On Error Resume Next
        .Range("Your User editable Range here").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Then in your change event use the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target.Cells
        .Locked = True
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried it.  I start that InitiateSheetProtection each time, changed my change event. It all works that same way as always. All what i write is proetected but those macros in colums F to I are always unprotected. Do i make something wrong?

Comment: The `InitiateSheetProtection` sub unlocks all cells on the sheet. Change the range to the area that you want to be unprotected. Have a look at my update. This will lock all the cells on your sheet before unlocking the blank cells in your defined part of the sheet (User Editable Area). I use error handling to handle the possibility of there being no blank cells

Answer (score 1):

Just run this from a public module code sheet once.

```
sub specialProtect()
    worksheet("whatever").unProtect Password:="Athens"
    worksheet("whatever").Protect Password:="Athens",  UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end sub
```

Now you can remove all of the .unprotect and .protect statements from the rest of your code. The user cannot change anything you have not allowed them to and your VBA can change anything.

Comment: But i want to protect only those cells that were alterated by users, or by my 2nd and 3rd code. All other cells should stay unprotected till change. Thats why i would like to block rows: F:I for users but leave unprotected for VBA

Comment: Then unlock the cells you want a user to be able to change prior to running the above snippet.

Comment: It's code for some kind of check list, i need to leave empty cells unprotected till they become some text from a user/VBA. Our Quality Department want to have them work that way. So you see, that i need code that allow my first one work as intended and one addittional, that protect cells edited by VBA

Comment: This will need to be run each time you open the workbook as closing it seems to lose the `UserInterFaceOnly` property

Comment: @Tom - It really shouldn't.

Comment: @Jeeped I wish it didn't - Have a look at the UserInterfaceOnly notes in this [linky](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm)

Comment: @jeeped your solution is working, but i don't want to leave cells with content from users unprotected. Each time any users use one cell it should be blocked. I need a way to block these few VBA target colums for users